# Как отловить нажатие TAB в WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно сделать в C# WinForms так, чтобы при фокусе на TextBox и нажатии TAB вставлялась табуляция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Tab && this.ActiveControl == sender)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tab");
        //textBox1.Text += "\t";
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}
```